# How to get incremental YouTube comments from videos using YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata

So given a YouTube video ID, how do I retrieve only the incremental (new) comments from the YouTube video?

For example, if I run the API query to return all the comments from the YouTube video (using the pagination and so forth) on a Monday and then run the API query again on Tuesday ONLY to retrieve the new comments that were published on that video (after my last API call), what are the parameters that I should be passing to the query?

I'm using the below to get the comments:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1'
```